# JSF do some action after all business logic's completed in a managed bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have the backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean{

    private boolean needUpdateData;
    private List<Object> data;
    //Other fields, GET, SET 

    public void doDataSearch(){
        needUpdateData = true;
    }

    public List<Object> retrieveData(){
        if(!needUpdateData)
             return data;
        //Otherwise, retrieve the data from a database from scratch
    }

    public void refresh(){
        needUpdateData = false;
    }
}
```

and the following piece of markup:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.doDataSearch}">
<!-- Paging and the table representing the data -->
```

I need the data to be udpdated only when we click the `commandButton`, that is after we click the `commandButton` and retrieve the data we'll set `needUpdateData` to false.

I would make the bean implementing `PhaseListener` as follows:

```
@Override
public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    needUpdateSummary = false;
}

@Override
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {

}

@Override
public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
    return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
}
```

But I'm not sure about it. Is it considered a good JSF-way to reach that?

Comment: The JSF `PhaseListener` acts as an interceptor. Managed beans involved should not be polluted with such cross-cutting concerns unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Tiny So where should I set the value then?